# Json array add onto php array

Tags: php

I want to acheive something simliar to this adding elements onto an array but when I use this methods two nodes get created in the json element. I only want one node with all the entires within that also can you name nodes ie Properties.

```
$json = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $json['name'] = $row['name'];
    $json['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data[] = $json;
}

$custom = array('name'=>'foo', 'id' => 'bar');
$data[] = $custom;
```

Comment: Can you add what you get and what you are expecting?

Comment: like this `{name: ["foo", "bar"], id: [1,2]}`???

Answer (score 0):

Try this code array_push is better option here,

```
    <?php
    $json = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp = array('name' => $row['name'], 'id' => $row['id']);
        array_push($json, $temp);
    }

    $custom = array('name'=>'foo', 'id' => 'bar');
    array_push($json,$custom);

   ?>
```

Comment: Why is `array_push()` better? It's just an additional function call. For the same as `$json[] = `. And why are you init `$temp` two times?

Comment: Which is simple to understand  $json['name'] = $row['name'];  $json['id'] = $row['id']; $data[] = $json; OR $temp = array(); $temp = array('name' => $row['name'], 'id' => $row['id']);  array_push($json, $temp);

Comment: Key is automatically maintained by array_push { $custom = array('name'=>'foo', 'id' => 'bar');
    array_push($json,$custom); }

Comment: The first one is better understandable. And key is also maintained automatically with `[] = `. We're working with PHP not Java ;-).

Comment: All variables are in the same scope.